# Problems using caret objects while knitting in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, r-caret

So when I knit the following code in `Rmarkdown` I get a specific error:

```
# Install caret.
install.packages("caret", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies=TRUE)
library(caret)

cross_val <- caret::trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, savePredictions=TRUE)

fit1 <- train(Class ~ Cl.thickness + Cell.size + Cell.shape + Marg.adhesion + 
                Epith.c.size + Bare.nuclei + Bl.cromatin + Normal.nucleoli + Mitoses, 
              data = BreastCancer[complete.cases(BreastCancer),], 
              method = "glm", family="binomial", trControl = cross_val, 
              tuneLength = 5, control = list(20))
```

The error is:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : object 'TrainControl' 
 not found Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> train -> train.formula -> train -> train.default
```

This is within RStudio, using R version 3.3.1 on 64-bit Windows 10. I've looked at some other posts and tried a few things with no changes thus far... `.libPaths()` gives me:

```
[1] "C:/Users/User Name/Documents/R/win-library/3.3"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library
```

`caret` is present in the `win-library/3.3` folder. I've tried resetting RStudio, unloading and reloading packages, updating packages, and reinstalling packages.

When I run the code in the RStudio console I get no errors and it runs to completion and produces results correctly. However, if I run the code in the console and then run the `Rmarkdown` code again, I get a different error:

```
Error in library(caret) : there is no package called 'caret' Calls: 
 <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> 
 library Execution halted
```

I'm sort of at a dead end right now, so any hints/clues would be much appreciated! (Please let me know if more information would help!)

EDIT 1:

I should have noted that the error occurs regardless of whether I use `trainControl` or `caret::trainControl`.

Answer (score 1):

I had come across this issue and in the process of attempting to reproduce it on a different PC I made an interesting discovery. A simple reproducible example:

````
```{r}
library(caret)

set.seed(1)
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10)
#Train the model 
step.model <- train(Fertility~., data = swiss,
                method = "leapBackward",
                tuneGrid = data.frame(nvmax = 1:5),
                trControl = train.control
                )

step.model$results

```
````

If you run this as a chunk, it returns a 5x7 table of performance stats.

Attempting to Knit the document, I would receive an error:

```
Error in trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10) : could not find function "trainControl" Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval Execution Halted
```

When I attempted to reproduce it I had the following YAML header and **knitted unsuccessfully**:

```
---
title: "Unable to Knit"
output: html_document
---
```

When I ran it on the new PC, my YAML header was and **knitted successfully**:

```
---
title: "Unable to Knit"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```

I returned to the first PC, with the successful YAML header and it **knitted successfully**

TL;DR: change you YAML header and try again